# Proper way to draw a tikz flowchart with arrows pointing back and forth between two nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I apologize if this is a duplicate, but I'm having a hard time finding an elegant solution. I have something that "works," but feels wonky.

I'm making a presentation in beamer and I want to have boxes with arrows pointing back and forth between objects. Here's a mwe with an idea of what I would like to achieve:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows,shapes}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \tikzstyle{service} = [draw, fill=blue!20]
  \begin{figure}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm, auto,>=latex', thick]
      \path[->] node[service] (svc1) {service 1};
      \path[->] node[service, right of=svc1,xshift=2cm] (svc2) {service 2}
                    (svc1.10) edge node {restarts} (svc2.170);
      \path[->] node[service, below of=svc2] (svc3) {service 3}
                    (svc2.280) edge node {configures} (svc3.80);
      \path[<-] (svc2.240) edge node {} (svc3.120);
      \path[<-] (svc1.-10) edge node {} (svc2.190);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

However, I believe that this seems like such a simple problem that a more elegant (automated) solution vs. putting in angles must exist.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A few tips to improve the code:

- Using `(svc1.10) edge node {restarts} (svc2.170)` might produce undesired results (not a perfectly horizontal rule) if the nodes are shifted; you can guarantee a horizontal line using the perpendicular coordinate system, as in

  ```
  (svc1.10) edge node {restarts} (svc2.west|-svc1.10)
  ```

  A similar remark for vertical rules. One might even define a style with arguments to automate a little this kind of double arrow.
- The syntax `of =` is deprecated, you should use the positioning library and `= of`.
- `\tikzstyle` is old syntax; you should use `\tikzset` instead.

The code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows,shapes,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\tikzset{service/.style={draw, fill=blue!20}}
  \begin{figure}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5cm and 2cm, auto,>=latex', thick]
      \path[->] node[service] (svc1) {service 1};
      \path[->] node[service, right = of svc1] (svc2) {service 2}
                    (svc1.10) edge node {restarts} (svc2.west|-svc1.10);
      \path[->] node[service, below = of svc2] (svc3) {service 3}
                    (svc2.280) edge node {configures} (svc2.280|-svc3.north);
      \path[<-] (svc2.240) edge node {} (svc2.240|-svc3.north);
      \path[<-] (svc1.-10) edge node {} (svc2.west|-svc1.-10);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for the quick reply! Can you explain what `(svc2.west|-svc1.10)` means? I'm guessing it would mean that this end should be at `svc2.west` and perpendicular to `-svc1.-10`. Come to think of it, I can't really put it in words...

Comment: @zestrada Sure. `(<a>|-(<b>))` has the `x`-coordinate of `<a>` and the `y`-coordinate of `<b>`; `(<a>-|(<b>))` has the `x`-coordinate of `<b>` and the `y`-coordinate of `<a>`.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`tikz-cd`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd)’s `shift right` and `shift left` option.

Though, it is not possible to do `edge[shift …=…]` but

```
(<start>) {[shift …=…] edge … (<target>)}
```

One need to re-write the options as a `to path` to be able to use them as options to the edge.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning}
\tikzset{
  shift left/.style ={commutative diagrams/shift left={#1}},
  shift right/.style={commutative diagrams/shift right={#1}}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance=1.5cm and 2cm,
  >=latex',
  auto,
  thick,
  service/.style={draw, fill=blue!20},
]
  \node[service] (svc1) {service 1};
  \node[service, right = of svc1] (svc2) {service 2};
  \node[service, below = of svc2] (svc3) {service 3};

  \path[->, shift left=.75ex]
    (svc1) edge node {restarts}   (svc2)
    (svc2) edge node {configures} (svc3)
    (svc3) edge                   (svc2)
    (svc2) edge                   (svc1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]