# How to draw a double-color line with TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw lines which have two colors along the complete length. In principle I could draw two lines next to each other which are slightly shifted, however, this seems like a whole lot of fiddling with coordinates to get everything right. Is there some generic way to do this, or has somebody already written something like this and made it so that it is portable?

A short example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [circle,fill] (e0) at (5,1.5) {};
  \node [circle,fill] (e1) at (0,0) {};
  \node [circle,fill] (e2) at (10,0) {};
  \node [circle,fill] (e4) at (5,3.5) {};
  \draw [ultra thick, blue] (e1) to  (e2);
  \draw [ultra thick, green] (e1) to (e4);
  \draw [ultra thick, blue](e1) to (e4);
  \draw [ultra thick, blue] (e2) to (e4);
  \draw (e1) to (e2);
  \draw [ultra thick, green] (e0) to (e1);
  \draw (e0) to (e2);
  \draw [ultra thick, green] (e0) to (e4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I would like the edge from `e1` to `e4` to be green and blue, with the green line running along the inside of the triangle and the blue line along the outside of the triangle.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. — What is the path made-up from? Only line-tos? Move-tos? Curves? For straight lines, this can be solved very easily.

Comment: I think we just missed each other. I was already adding a MWE. ;-) Although I have to admit that it is not minimal, but just small.

Comment: Ah, yes; the rest still stands: only straight lines? See [this answer that uses `tikz-cd`’s options](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/133917/16595) or [Draw additional parallel paths in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102975) and [for closed polygons](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/133670/16595). Just set the distance to `.5\pgflinewidth` or `-.5\pgflinewidth`.

Comment: Thanks. That is exactly what I need. I used the [Draw additional parallel paths in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102975) solution.