# Creating a punktchain or flow diagram in tikz/pgf latex that is two column then merges to one and back to two

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-trees

I have update the example code with some of the comments to get really close to what I want. Now I just want two lines coming out of filter 1 and filter 2 inline and with the same line style as already there for the smaller blocks. I assume this should be relatively easy but I can only figure out how to get the lines out of the center of the block.

```
\makeatletter
\tikzset{west above/.code=\tikz@lib@place@handle@{#1}{south west}{0}{1}{north west}{1}}
\tikzset{west below/.code=\tikz@lib@place@handle@{#1}{north west}{0}{-1}{south west}{1}}
\tikzset{east above/.code=\tikz@lib@place@handle@{#1}{south east}{0}{1}{north east}{1}}
\tikzset{east below/.code=\tikz@lib@place@handle@{#1}{north east}{0}{-1}{south east}{1}}
\makeatother
\fontsize{8pt}{9pt}\selectfont
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every node/.style={
    rectangle, 
    rounded corners, 
    % fill=black!10,
    draw=black, very thick,
    minimum height=2em, 
    inner sep=2pt,
    text centered, 
    align=center
  },
  big node/.style={text width=8cm},
  small node/.style={text width=3.5cm},
  >=latex, %Make the arrow tips latex
  myline/.style={draw, very thick,black, <-, node distance=1.1cm},
  mylinedot/.style={draw, very thick, blue!100!black!70, densely dotted, <-, node distance=1cm},
  shorter/.style={shorten <=1mm,shorten >=0.5mm},
  node distance=0.75cm,
  |*/.style={to path=(\tikztostart.south) -- (\tikztostart.south|-\tikztotarget.north)},
  *|/.style={to path=(\tikztostart.south-|\tikztotarget.north) -- (\tikztotarget.north)}
  ]
\begin{scope}[every node/.append style={big node}]
  \node (B) {\textbf{Filter process 1}};
  \node[below=of B] (C) {\textbf{Filter process 2}};
  \node[below=of C] (D) {\textbf{Filter process 3}};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[every node/.append style={small node}]
  \node[west above=of B] (A1) {\textsc{Training Waveform}};
  \node[east above=of B] (A2) {\textsc{Testing Waveform}};

  \node[west below=of D] (E1) {\textbf{Reduced Model}};
  \node[east below=of D] (E2) {\textbf{Full Model}};

\end{scope}
% \path (A1) -- node[F5 node] {F5} (A2);

\path[myline,->,shorter]  {[|*] (A1) edge (B)}
                                (B)  edge (C)
                                (C)  edge (D)
                          {[*|] (D)  edge (E1)}
                         ;
\path[mylinedot,->,shorter]  {[|*] (A2) edge (B) }
                          {[*|] (D) edge (E2)}
                          (E1) edge (E2)
                         ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Flow Diagram]

This is the final solution but I get a miscellaneous arrow that I am not sure how to get rid of. All I did was change to the two path lines below from the above code with no other changes.

Code is here:

```
\path[myline,->,shorter]  {[|*] (A1) edge (B)}
                              ([shift={(-2.25cm,0)}]B.south)  edge ([shift={(-2.25cm,0)}]C.north)
                              ([shift={(-2.25cm,0)}]C.south)  edge ([shift={(-2.25cm,0)}]D.north)
                          {[*|] (D)  edge (E1)}
                         ;
\path[mylinedot,->,shorter]  {[|*] (A2) edge (B) }
                              ([shift={(2.25cm,0)}]B.south)  edge ([shift={(2.25cm,0)}]C.north)
                              ([shift={(2.25cm,0)}]C.south)  edge ([shift={(2.25cm,0)}]D.north)
                          {[*|] (D) edge (E2)}
                          (E1) edge (E2)
                         ;
```

[image: Flow Diagram2]

Comment: You might find [Converging and diverging nodes in a flowchart](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/121665) and [How to Make This Block Diagram with LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/132897) helpful.

Comment: Simply use edge without using in/out angle. That is, remove [in=xx, out=yy] options.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel - The only thing I can not figure out from those links is how to get two straight lines out of filter process 1 and filter process 2. Check my example above as I can only get the line out of the middle. I want two lines coming out with the styles following the training and testing.

Comment: @Jesse I tried that but got somewhat the desired result but had already looked at Qrr's links and prefered that method more. Still have not figured out entirely how to do it correctly so look at my post above.

Comment: @JSpen Ah, then, [Proper way to draw a tikz flowchart with arrows pointing back and forth between two nodes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/131803) will also be helpful.

Comment: @J Spen -- My post did just that. Look for '\path[connector..]' in my post and use the the techniques ([shift={(1cm,0)}]A2.south) edge (coordinate).

Comment: @Jesse Yes I am trying that now. Let you know if I have any issues.

Comment: @Jesse I have it all working except that I get an extra arrow. I am not sure what is causing it. I will post above in the question.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Ended up just using shift and added the figure above which is what I want except I get a set of extra arrows in filter process 2. I don't know what is causing this.

Comment: @JSpen -- This is only an idea, hoping it will work out. Could you please try forming those 4 modified lines into another independent \path command, so that they are not affected by your 'myline' and 'mylinedot' style.

Comment: @Jesse Thanks that seemed to work just fine. All is good and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you seek? Basically the in/out angle options for `edge [in=..., out=...]` are removed and the connected lines/pathes between blocks are not centered, but moved aside, so that train path and test path are clearly seen.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[papersize={14cm,14cm}]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,shapes.arrows, arrows, positioning}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{>=stealth',
    punktchain/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, 
    % fill=black!10,
    draw=black, very thick,
    inner sep=2pt, text width=3.1cm, minimum height=3em, 
    text centered, on chain},
  connector/.style = {->,very thick},
  punktchain1/.style={ rectangle,  rounded corners, 
    % fill=black!10,
    draw=black, very thick,
    inner sep=2pt,text width=3.2cm,  minimum height=3em, 
    text centered,  on chain},
  line/.style={draw, very thick, <-},
  element/.style={tape,top color=white,
    bottom color=blue!50!black!60!,
    minimum width=8em, draw=blue!40!black!90, very thick,
    text width=10em,  minimum height=3.5em, 
    text centered,  on chain},
  every join/.style={->, very thick, shorten >=1pt},    
  %decoration={brace, segment length=10pt, amplitude=7pt},
  tuborg/.style={decorate, very thick},
  tubnode/.style={midway, right=5pt}
}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\small % \fontsize{8pt}{9pt}\selectfont
\begin{tikzpicture} [auto, >=stealth',  node distance=1cm,  start chain=going below]

\node[punktchain ] (A1) {\textsc{Train Path}};

\node[punktchain, right = 0.7cm of A1] (B1) { \textsc{Test Path}};

\node[punktchain, text width = 7cm, below = of A1, xshift=2cm] (A2)  {
    \begin{tabular}{c}
    \textbf{Step 1} \\
    \parbox{6cm}{  $\bullet$ Bullet 1 \\ $\bullet$ Bullet 2}
    \end{tabular}
    };
     \path [connector] (A1)  edge   (A2);    
     \path [connector, densely dotted] (B1.south) edge (A2);    
%     \path \[line, densely dotted\]<3-3> (A4) edge \[out=0, in=184\] (pic);
%     \node\[punktchain, join\] (A22) {\textbf{Rectify and Integrate} \\ \vspace{} ($10$ms windows)};
     \node[punktchain, text width = 7cm] (A3) {\textbf{Step 2}};
     \path [connector, densely dotted] ([shift={(1cm,0)}]A2.south) edge ([shift={(1cm,0)}]A3.north);   
\path [connector, very thick] ([shift={(-1cm,0)}]A2.south) edge ([shift={(-1cm,0)}]A3.north);  
     \node[punktchain, text width = 7cm] (A4) {
        \begin{tabular}{c}
          \textbf{Step 3} \\
          \parbox{6.5cm}{Something written here}
        \end{tabular}};
     \path [connector, densely dotted] ([shift={(1cm,0)}]A3.south) edge ([shift={(1cm,0)}]A4.north);    
\path [connector, very thick] ([shift={(-1cm,0)}]A3.south) edge ([shift={(-1cm,0)}]A4.north);    
     \node[punktchain,  below= of A4, xshift=-2cm] (A6) {\textbf{Final Store}}; 
     \node[punktchain, below= of A4, xshift=2cm] (A8) {\textbf{Compare} }; 
     \path [connector, densely dotted] (A6) edge  (A8);    
     \path [connector, densely dotted] (A4) edge  (A8);    
     \path  [connector] (A4)  edge   (A6);    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**Updated**:  The OP has an updated version. Actually, the answer addressed above still covers the new post's need. By using the `shift={(x,y)}` skill, the expected result is achievable.

[image]

```
Code:

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[papersize={14cm,14cm}]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,shapes.arrows, arrows, positioning, fadings,decorations}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{>=stealth',
    punktchain/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, 
    % fill=black!10,
    draw=black, very thick,
    inner sep=2pt, text width=3.1cm, minimum height=3em, 
    text centered, on chain},
  connector/.style = {->,very thick},
  punktchain1/.style={ rectangle,  rounded corners, 
    % fill=black!10,
    draw=black, very thick,
    inner sep=2pt,text width=3.2cm,  minimum height=3em, 
    text centered,  on chain},
  line/.style={draw, very thick, <-},
  element/.style={tape,top color=white,
    bottom color=blue!50!black!60!,
    minimum width=8em, draw=blue!40!black!90, very thick,
    text width=10em,  minimum height=3.5em, 
    text centered,  on chain},
  every join/.style={->, very thick, shorten >=1pt},    
     %decoration={brace, segment length=10pt, amplitude=7pt},
  tuborg/.style={decorate, very thick},
  tubnode/.style={midway, right=5pt}
}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\small % \fontsize{8pt}{9pt}\selectfont
\begin{tikzpicture} [auto, >=stealth',  node distance=1cm,  start chain=going below]

\node[punktchain ] (A1) {\textsc{Train Path}};

\node[punktchain, right = 0.7cm of A1] (B1) { \textsc{Test Path}};

\node[punktchain, text width = 7cm, below = of A1, xshift=2cm] (A2)  {
    \begin{tabular}{c}
    \textbf{Step 1} \\
    \parbox{6cm}{  $\bullet$ Bullet 1 \\ $\bullet$ Bullet 2}
    \end{tabular}
    };
     \path [connector] (A1.south)  edge   ([shift={(-2cm,0)}]A2.north);    
     \path [connector, densely dotted] (B1.south) edge   ([shift={(2cm,0)}]A2.north);    
%     \path \[line, densely dotted\]<3-3> (A4) edge \[out=0, in=184\] (pic);
%     \node\[punktchain, join\] (A22) {\textbf{Rectify and Integrate} \\ \vspace{} ($10$ms windows)};
     \node[punktchain, text width = 7cm] (A3) {\textbf{Step 2}};
     \path [connector, densely dotted] ([shift={(2cm,0)}]A2.south)   edge   ([shift={(2cm,0)}]A3.north);   
\path [connector, very thick] ([shift={(-2cm,0)}]A2.south)   edge   ([shift={(-2cm,0)}]A3.north);  
     \node[punktchain, text width = 7cm] (A4) {
        \begin{tabular}{c}
         \textbf{Step 3} \\
          \parbox{6.5cm}{Something written here}
    \end{tabular}};
     \path [connector, densely dotted] ([shift={(2cm,0)}]A3.south)   edge   ([shift={(2cm,0)}]A4.north);    
\path [connector, very thick] ([shift={(-2cm,0)}]A3.south)   edge   ([shift={(-2cm,0)}]A4.north);    
     \node[punktchain,  below= of A4, xshift=-2cm] (A6) {\textbf{Final Store}}; 
     \node[punktchain, below= of A4, xshift=2cm] (A8) {\textbf{Compare} }; 
     \path [connector, densely dotted] (A6) edge  (A8);    
     \path [connector, densely dotted] ([shift={(2cm,0)}]A4.south) edge  (A8.north);    
    \path  [connector] ([shift={(-2cm,0)}]A4.south)  edge   (A6.north);    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is close to what I want. I was also working on an example from the links provided in the post and I posted the edited solution. I still don't know how to get straight lines down as desired which you have in this example. If you know how to get straight lines down from my posted example since you have done that here just post that and I will accept the answer. Or I can try to figure it out from your code.

Comment: @JSpen -- I just leave a message in your post, specific lines are mentioned to you for your reference. Yes, I believe you are very close to your solution.

Comment: Thanks because the shift works well but get extra arrows in my code that when I pasted yours I did not get.

Answer (score 2):

<sub>Too long for a comment.</sub>

You are defining

```
myline/.style={draw, very thick,black, <-, node distance=1.1cm},
mylinedot/.style={draw, very thick, blue!100!black!70, densely dotted, <-, node distance=1cm},
```

i.e, to have arrow head backwards. And in your `\path` command, you are using `->` arrows in the forward direction. Remove `->` from the definition of  `myline/.style` and `mylinedot/.style` and use `->` as an option to every edge like `edge[->]`. i.e.,

```
\path[myline,,shorter]  {[|*] (A1) edge[->] (B)}
                              ([shift={(-2.25cm,0)}]B.south)  edge[->] ([shift={(-2.25cm,0)}]C.north)
                              ([shift={(-2.25cm,0)}]C.south)  edge[->] ([shift={(-2.25cm,0)}]D.north)
                          {[*|] (D)  edge[->] (E1)}
                         ;
\path[mylinedot,shorter]  {[|*] (A2) edge[->] (B) }
                             ([shift={(2.25cm,0)}]B.south)  edge[->] ([shift={(2.25cm,0)}]C.north)
                              ([shift={(2.25cm,0)}]C.south)  edge[->] ([shift={(2.25cm,0)}]D.north)
                          {[*|] (D) edge[->] (E2)}
                          (E1) edge[->] (E2)
                         ;
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[papersize={14cm,14cm}]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,shapes.arrows, arrows, positioning}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{west above/.code=\tikz@lib@place@handle@{#1}{south west}{0}{1}{north west}{1}}
\tikzset{west below/.code=\tikz@lib@place@handle@{#1}{north west}{0}{-1}{south west}{1}}
\tikzset{east above/.code=\tikz@lib@place@handle@{#1}{south east}{0}{1}{north east}{1}}
\tikzset{east below/.code=\tikz@lib@place@handle@{#1}{north east}{0}{-1}{south east}{1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\fontsize{8pt}{9pt}\selectfont
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every node/.style={
    rectangle,
    rounded corners,
    % fill=black!10,
    draw=black, very thick,
    minimum height=2em,
    inner sep=2pt,
    text centered,
    align=center
  },
  big node/.style={text width=8cm},
  small node/.style={text width=3.5cm},
  >=latex, %Make the arrow tips latex
  myline/.style={draw, very thick,black, node distance=1.1cm},
  mylinedot/.style={draw, very thick, blue!100!black!70, densely dotted,  node distance=1cm},
  shorter/.style={shorten <=1mm,shorten >=0.5mm},
  node distance=0.75cm,
  |*/.style={to path=(\tikztostart.south) -- (\tikztostart.south|-\tikztotarget.north)},
  *|/.style={to path=(\tikztostart.south-|\tikztotarget.north) -- (\tikztotarget.north)}
  ]
\begin{scope}[every node/.append style={big node}]
  \node (B) {\textbf{Filter process 1}};
  \node[below=of B] (C) {\textbf{Filter process 2}};
  \node[below=of C] (D) {\textbf{Filter process 3}};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[every node/.append style={small node}]
  \node[west above=of B] (A1) {\textsc{Training Waveform}};
  \node[east above=of B] (A2) {\textsc{Testing Waveform}};

  \node[west below=of D] (E1) {\textbf{Reduced Model}};
  \node[east below=of D] (E2) {\textbf{Full Model}};

\end{scope}
\path[myline,,shorter]  {[|*] (A1) edge[->] (B)}
                              ([shift={(-2.25cm,0)}]B.south)  edge[->] ([shift={(-2.25cm,0)}]C.north)
                              ([shift={(-2.25cm,0)}]C.south)  edge[->] ([shift={(-2.25cm,0)}]D.north)
                          {[*|] (D)  edge[->] (E1)}
                         ;
\path[mylinedot,shorter]  {[|*] (A2) edge[->] (B) }
                             ([shift={(2.25cm,0)}]B.south)  edge[->] ([shift={(2.25cm,0)}]C.north)
                              ([shift={(2.25cm,0)}]C.south)  edge[->] ([shift={(2.25cm,0)}]D.north)
                          {[*|] (D) edge[->] (E2)}
                          (E1) edge[->] (E2)
                         ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks that worked. I had already modified the code similarly so I used a different path command for the large blocks which also worked from Jesse suggestion.